# VBA written in Excel for Windows not working on Mac

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I have a set of macros to hide and unhide columns based on the contents of a specific row. They were all written in Excel 2013 for Windows (running in parallels on my MBA, if that's relevant) and work fine there. But when I open the worksheet in Excel 2011 for Mac, the macros give odd results. The "unhide all columns" macro works fine; the other functions get as far as hiding all columns but not as far as unhiding the ones I want to see.

I can only assume Excel for Mac is having a problem with what's in the FOR EACH loop, but I can't figure out what! I'd appreciate any guidance: I need to get this system working on both Windows and Mac.

Code below.

This function works:

```
Sub GANTT_Filter_Show_All()

Dim rngDates As Range

Set rngDates = Range("GANTT_Dates")

rngDates.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

But this one only hides all the columns:

```
Sub GANTT_Filter_This_Quarter()

Dim intCurrentMonth As Integer, intCurrentYear As Integer, rngDates As Range, cell As Range
Dim intCurrentQuarterMonths(3) As Integer

Set rngDates = Range("GANTT_Dates")
intCurrentMonth = DatePart("m", Date)
intCurrentYear = DatePart("yyyy", Date)

'loading months of current quarter into an array intCurrentMonth

Select Case intCurrentMonth
    Case 1 To 3
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(0) = 1
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(1) = 2
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(2) = 3
    Case 4 To 6
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(0) = 4
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(1) = 5
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(2) = 6
    Case 7 To 9
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(0) = 7
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(1) = 8
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(2) = 9
    Case 10 To 12
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(0) = 10
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(1) = 11
        intCurrentQuarterMonths(2) = 12
    End Select

'hiding all columns

rngDates.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

'comparing each column to array of months in current quarter and hiding if false

For Each cell In rngDates
    For Each v In intCurrentQuarterMonths
        If v = DatePart("m", cell.Value) And DatePart("yyyy", cell.Value) = intCurrentYear Then cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Next v
Next cell

Application.Goto Reference:=Range("a1"), Scroll:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code and I am not familiar with Mac Excel's VBA implementation. I would suggest putting in a break point and stepping through the For Each to check the values are as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did that, with a Debug.Print in the innermost For Each loop. It looks like DatePart("m", cell.Value) is returning the same value as DatePart("yyyy", cell.Value), which would explain why the loop isn't doing anything useful. _Why_ it's happening is a mystery, though, and I can't see how to fix it. I can't find any documentation on DatePart misbehaving in Excel for Mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: It feels a bit defeatist to avoid using DatePart but you could try using this Month(cell.Value) and Year(cell.Value).

Comment: What are you intending to do with the `For each v` loop? Right now it looks like you're evaluating `DatePart("m", cell.Value)` as a Boolean. That seems wrong to me, or at least seems like something that could yield unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks! @Steven's suggestion (and Comintern's more detailed answer) sorted it right out. Defeatist it may be but I'm not too proud to do what works.  
  
David: the `For each v` compares the cell's month to each of the months in the current quarter, and compares the cell's year to the current year, and if both of those are true then it hides the cell's column (that bit's off to the right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm with @Steven on this one, nothing obviously wrong with the code. I'm not a Mac user, but it's entirely possible that there's some weirdness around the date functions, particularly those that require formatting to resolve.

I would try replacing the calls to DatePart() with calls to Month() and Year() in situations like this - even for non-Mac users.  It doesn't rely on parsing the strings for formatting, so it's much more efficient (and easy to read):

```
Sub Benchmarks()

    Dim starting As Double, test As Date, i As Long
    test = Now

    starting = Timer
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        Year test
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Elapsed: " & (Timer - starting)

    starting = Timer
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        DatePart "yyyy", test
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Elapsed: " & (Timer - starting)

End Sub
```

Since you likely can't run the benchmark...

```
Elapsed for Year():     0.109375
Elapsed for DatePart(): 0.515625
```

Also note that in addition to this, the dates in the column you're searching are coming through as Variants, it may help to explicitly cast them to dates:

```
If v = Month(CDate(cell.Value)) And intCurrentYear = Year(CDate(cell.Value)) Then
    cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Problem solved, and I've learned a little more VBA in the process.